# Align multiple unordered lists on the same line

Tags: html, css

I want to put multiple `<ul>` on the same line, simulating products in a shop. So far I've got multiple unordered list tags:

```css
ul {
  display: inline;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://au.alexu.edu.eg/English/Academics/PublishingImages/Central%20Library%20Logo%20Design%20-%20English.png" width="20%" height="20%" /></li>
  <li>Name</li>
  <li>Author</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><img src="http://au.alexu.edu.eg/English/Academics/PublishingImages/Central%20Library%20Logo%20Design%20-%20English.png" width="20%" height="20%" /></li>
  <li>Name</li>
  <li>Author</li>
</ul>
```

How can I accomplish this? I have them show vertically but I dont want them this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set it to `ul {display:inline-block;}`.

Be aware of `width="20%" height="20%"` on the image in your example, it may give you unwanted results. As percentage width or height is always relative to container's width, not itself.

For simplicity, I just use fixed width in the demo below.

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><img src="//dummyimage.com/100"></li>
  <li>Name</li>
  <li>Author</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><img src="//dummyimage.com/100"></li>
  <li>Name</li>
  <li>Author</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
li{
  float:left;
}
```

floating left will fix it..

Comment: You can add margin-left:10px or how many you want in order to separate the list items a bit..

Comment: If I use this, the images remain the same, one on each line, but I get all the text on the same line after the first image.

Comment: That's not what you wanted? maybe float left the ul?